# Debugging IO errors in Python bus.write_byte

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

Trying to send Mouse xy coordinates from a raspberry pi to a connected arduino via i2C.

The following Python script works on the RPi

```
import smbus
import time
# for RPI version 1, use "bus = smbus.SMBus(0)"
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# This is the address we setup in the Arduino Program
address = 0x04

def writeNumber(value):
    bus.write_byte(address, value)
    # bus.write_byte_data(address, 0, value)
    return -1

def readNumber():
    number = bus.read_byte(address)
    # number = bus.read_byte_data(address, 1)
    return number

while True:
    var = input("Enter 1 - 9: ")
    if not var:
        continue

    writeNumber(var)
    print "RPI: Hi Arduino, I sent you ", var
    # sleep one second
    #time.sleep(1)

    number = readNumber()
    print "Arduino: Hey RPI, I received a digit ", number
    print
```

But when I try and merge the above code with preexisting Python class that gives me mouse XY coordinates, I keep getting an IO error  on the writeNumber method, specifically in the following line

```
self.bus.write_byte(self.address, value)
```

Here is the complete Python class. Can any Python experts suggest what might be wrong, or what troubleshooting steps I might take for IO errors?

```
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk

    import smbus
    import time


except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk

class MouseXY(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self._root = root
        # for RPI version 1, use "bus = smbus.SMBus(0)"
        self.bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

        # This is the address we setup in the Arduino Program
        self.address = 0x04

        self.createCanvas()
    def createCanvas(self):
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self._root, bg='white')
        canvas.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='nwes')
        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.clicked)
        canvas.bind("<Enter>", self.entered)
        canvas.bind('<Motion>', self.motion)

    def clicked(self, event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        s = "Last point clicked at x=%s  y=%s" % (x, y)
        self._root.title(s)
        print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
    def entered(self, event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        s = "Cursor at x=%s  y=%s" % (x, y)
        self._root.title(s)
    def motion(self,event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
        self.writeNumber(x)
        print "RPI: Hi Arduino, I sent you ", x
        print
    def writeNumber(self,value):       
        print "writeNumber  self.bus ",  self.bus       
        print "writeNumber  self.address ",  self.address
        print "writeNumber  value ",  value
        self.bus.write_byte(self.address, value)
        return -1

def createFunction():
    pass
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MouseXY(root)

    root.mainloop()
if  __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Show full error message.

Comment: if you run it on Python3 then `import Tkinter as tk` fail and you don't import `smbus`